# Unit normal to origin vs unit normal to point $x$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in C^2(U)$ be harmonic, $u:\bar{U}\subset \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$. $$\phi(r) := \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y) dS(y)= \int_{\partial B(0,1)} u(x+rz) dS(z)$$

Then:
$$\phi'(r) = \int_{\partial B(0,1)} Du(x+rz)\cdot z dS(z)$$
and $y=x+rz\implies z = \frac{y-x}{r}$.

So $$\phi'(r) = \int_{\partial B(x,r)} Du(y)\cdot \frac{y-x}{r} dS(y)$$

Then $y\in \partial B(x,r)\implies y-x\in \partial B(0,r)\implies \frac{y-x}{r}\in \partial B(0,1)$ right?

But Evans uses the following:

$$Du\cdot \nu = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}$$
where as I understand it $\nu$ is the unit normal at $x$, whereas $\frac{y-x}{r}$ is unit normal at the origin?

So how do I jump from $$\phi'(r)= \int_{\partial B(x,r)} Du(y)\cdot \frac{y-x}{r} dS(y)= \int_{\partial B(x,r)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} dS(y)?$$

Comment: No, $\nu$ and $\dfrac{y-x}{r}$ are normal unit vectors at $y$ (on the boundary of $B$). With the due cautions, we can say that they are the same vector.

Comment: @RafaBudría I just don't see how that is the case. If $y\in \partial B(x,r)$ then surely $y=x+rz$ where $\|z\|=1$, and hence $\frac{y-x}{r}$ is a point on $\partial B(0,1)$, not on $\partial B(x,1)$?

Comment: You are right and me too :) $z$ points **at** some point on $\partial B(0,1)$ and it is too the normal unit vector at $z$ in the first integral for $\phi'$ (I said some mesleadingly, "at $y$"). So understood, in the second integral for $\phi$ we are "moving" this vector to $\partial B(x,r)$, so is at $y$. Continue...

Comment: We have the normal unit vector at $y$, so, the differential at $y$, $Du$ dotted with this vector, $\nu$, is the value of the directional derivative of $u$ along the unit normal at $y$, $\nu$. You can see it from a slightly different point of view: $y-x$ can be seen as a vector joining $x$ and $y$ (and it has length $r$! because $y$ is in the boundary of $B$). You divide by $r$ and we have a unit vector pointing along the line joining $x$ and $y$, so, it is a vector normal to $\partial B(x,r)$ (a ball, so is, a sphere), it is of length $1$ and points to $y$. It's the unit normal at $y$, $\nu$.